# Error sending emails to Gmail API using HTTP request

Tags: gmail-api

I am trying to send emails using the Gmail API with HTTP request.
Reference link: https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/send

My sample code to call the API:-

```
/*HTTP Request*/
POST https://www.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/{userId}/messages/send

/*Headers:*/
Authorization: Bearer {accesstoken}
Content-Type: message/rfc822

/*Request body*/
{"raw":"RnJvbTogamhvbndpbHNvbi5lY3Npb25AZ21haWwuY29tIApUbzogaW1yYWFuQGVjc2lvbi5jb20gClN1YmplY3Q6IFNheWluZyBIZWxsbyAKRGF0ZTogMDYtQXVnLTIwMTggMTM6NTA6MzEgKzA1IApNZXNzYWdlLUlEOiA8MTIzNEBsb2NhbC5tYWNoaW5lLmV4YW1wbGU-CgpUaGlzIGlzIGEgbWVzc2FnZSBqdXN0IHRvIHNheSBoZWxsby4gU28sICJIZWxsbyIu"}
```

---

After initiating the request the API returns the following json response:

```
{ "error": { "errors": [ { "domain": "global", "reason": "wrongUrlForUpload", "message": "Uploads must be sent to the upload URL. Re-send this request to https://www.googleapis.com/upload/gmail/v1/users/{userId}/messages/send" } ], "code": 400, "message": "Uploads must be sent to the upload URL. Re-send this request to https://www.googleapis.com/upload/gmail/v1/users/{userId}/messages/send" } }
```

Note - I am not passing any attachment to the email.

Please do let me know what I am doing wrong in the request.

Comment: That is a complete RFC822-format message you've included, is it? There's no chance that gmail is attempting to parse it and deciding it's not a message?

Comment: Your request works fine in the Google API Explorer (you probably got an email from me!).  See:  https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/send